# How to remove the authentication token "roles" to implement a MFA system?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony4

I want to integrate a secondary authentication measure for a subset of users after they login:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    $user = $token->getUser();

    if ($user->getOrganization()->getMfa() {

        //$token->setAuthenticated(false);
        $token->setRoles(null);

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('mfa'));
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('home'));
}
```

I would then like to validate the security code in a different controller:

```
if((int)$session->get('authCode') === (int)$request->get('auth_code')) {

    //$token->setAuthenticated(true);
    $token->setRoles($user->getRoles());

    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('home'));
}
```

The issue with `setAutheticated(false)` is that I lose access to the `$user` object after the method completes.

I'm thinking about removing the roles granted to the user; but I cannot figure out how to remove roles from an existing token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the roles property of token. As you have seen, the `TokenInterface` does not include a setter for the roles.

And you can't `setAuthenticated(false)`, because then you would be clearing the first authentication *factor*, and going bac to zero.

But I believe you are approaching the problem the wrong way.

Leave the token as it is, and use the listener for `onAuthenticationSuccess` to check  `User::organization::getMfa()` to decide if you need to:

- send the user the secondary authentication code,
- store somewhere that you are the authentication is not finished (e.g. in the session, in the DB in a user property, a separate store for this, etc).

(Personally, I would make the requirement of MFA another role, so that could be stored on the token and you wouldn't need to check additional things for this).

Then, create a [event subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#component-http-kernel-kernel-request) for **each** request.

On that listener you would inject `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security`  to access the user and see if `User::organization::getMfa() === true`;  and whatever means to check if the authentication is not finished (e.g., if you stored in the session, or check the user entity directly, etc).

- If you do not have a token, you `return`, this is a non-authenticated view and it's not the listeners problem.
- If the user does not require MFA, you just `return`; nothing to do here.
- If the user requires MFA but it is not in the middle of an authentication process, you `return`. This means the user has been already authenticated completely, and they can carry on.
- If the user requires MFA and is in the middle of an authentication process, you display whatever means to finish it. Typically a form.
- If the user requires MFA and is in the middle of an authentication process **and they are sending you the means to check this authentication** (e.g. a POST request with the appropriate fields), you verify that the authentication is good.
- Is the verification good? You clear the "authentication in process" bit, and return. Further requests won't be intercepted.
- Is the verification bad? You either let them check again, re-send the verification codes, log the user out completely so they start again... What exactly would depend very much on your requirements.

The complete code implementation would be up to you, because it's impossibly broad to cover all possible scenarios.

But your subscriber could be something like this, to start with (notice that there are a couple of unimplemented methods as well).

```php
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class MfaSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {

        if ($event->getRequestType() === HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ( null == $token = $this->security->getToken()) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! in_array('ROLE_NEEDS_MFA', $token->getRoleNames(), true)) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! $request->hasPreviousSession() || ! $request->getSession()->get('AUTHENTICATION_IN_PROCESS')) {
            return;
        }

        if (
            $request->getMethod() === Request::METHOD_POST
            && $request->get('verification_code')
            && $this->verifyCode($request->get('verification_code')) // verify code needs to be implemented
        ) {
            $request->getSession()->set('AUTHENTICATION_IN_PROCESS', null);

            return;
        }

        $event->setResponse($this->displayMfaVerificationMethod($request, $token));

    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onRequest',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your considered response